# Let $X$,$Y$ be infinite dimensional subspaces of $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ and $T:X \to Y$ a bounded linear operator. Does it exist bounded $T^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $1 \leq p < q < \infty$

Let $X$ be a infinite dimensione subspace (not closed) of $\ell^p$

Let $Y$ be a infinite dimensione subspace (not closed) of $\ell^q$

Let $T : X \to Y$ be a  bijective bounded linear operator

My question is if is it possible that $T^{-1}$ is bounded (not in general)

It seems that "Pitt's Theorem" answers "no" to my question but in my case the spaces aren't closed, so what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $T^{-1} : Y \to X$ is bounded. Then so is $T^{-1} : Y \to \ell^p$, so that it has a continuous extension $S : \overline{Y}\to \ell^p$, which is compact by Pitt's theorem. Note that in fact $S : \overline{Y} \to \overline{X}$, not necessarily surjective.

Likewise, $T$ extends to a bounded operator $R : \overline{X} \to \ell^q$. Now, for $y \in Y$, we have $R S y = R T^{-1} y = T T^{-1} y = y$. By continuity this shows $RS = I_{\overline{Y}}$, so that the identity operator on $\overline{Y}$ is compact as a composition of a continuous and a compact operator. But it is well known that the identity on an infinite dimensional Banach space is never compact.

Comment: can you explain me why you extend $RS=I_{Y}$ to $RS=I_{\overline{Y}}$, thanks anyhow.

Comment: @Matey: I think at the time when I wrote this answer, I was not completely sure whether the identity is never compact on an infinite dimensional normed vector space or only on infinite dimensional Banach spaces (i.e., whether one needs completeness). To be sure I extended everything to the closure. Related to this, the following paper could be interesting: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086906000442

Comment: OK @PhoemueX  thanks, now it's clear